# How to make GORM create an index on Map?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my Grails 2.3.7 project, I have a Product domain class, like this:

```
class Product {
    String code
    String description
    Map attributes

    static constraints = {
        code(unique: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        code index: 'Code_Idx'
        attributes fetch: 'join'
        cache true
        id generator: 'hilo'
    }
}
```

It translates into this database:

```
create table product (id bigint not null, version bigint not null, code varchar(255) not null unique, description varchar(255) not null, primary key (id));
create table product_attributes (attributes bigint, attributes_idx varchar(255), attributes_elt varchar(255) not null);
create index Code_Idx on product (code);
```

With some 4000 products in database, the scaffold listing shows them just fine.

Except, when I click "sort" on code - because there is no index - so my server does this:

```
explain select this_.id as id14_0_, this_.version as version14_0_, this_.code as code14_0_, this_.description as descript4_14_0_, 
attributes2_.attributes as attributes14_2_, attributes2_.attributes_elt as attributes3_2_, attributes2_.attributes_idx as attributes2_2_ 
from product this_ left outer join product_attributes attributes2_ 
on this_.id=attributes2_.attributes 
order by lower(this_.code) desc limit 90, 100

+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_        | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  4086 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | attributes2_ | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 43975 |                                 |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Obviously, this takes ages. I can manually add the index:

```
ALTER TABLE `product_attributes` ADD INDEX(`attributes`);
```

and then it works OK. I think it should have been created automatically in the first place - there is very little sense in this schema without the index - but OK, I can ping Gorm to do it. My question is - what can I put into the domain class to have Gorm add this index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails doesn't automatically create indexes on such columns as 'attributes' in your example. In order to create and manage these indexes I highly recommend using the [Database Migration Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration). The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/index.html) is well written, and outlines how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Joshua. But it seems almost as non-portable as running an 'ALTER TABLE' from application code - it may not work if the underlying engine somehow decides that the names should be different, never mind the fact that it won't make any sense for a NoSQL storage. I am planning to deploy my project on many different servers, some probably configured differently than others. I would think that making of such index should be controlled by Gorm itself, at the very least with a hint. I guess I needed a confirmation it is an omission that should be reported to the Grails guys.

Comment: The problem you are facing is the same that Grails itself would face. What SQL (or NoSQL) dialect to use. It's not uncommon for projects (Spring Batch comes to mind) to offer all the supporting ALTER/Setup scripts in various dialects and allow the person deploying the application decide which to include/apply. I realize this isn't automated but if you want something fully automated (with multiple dialects supported) then you will have to design/implement that as a part of your application.

Comment: Josh, I understand that optimizations may not be trivial - so I am really grateful for your suggestions. Looks like DBM will be useful even during development. This case however should be simple enough for Gorm to be handled nicely and portably. It's a shame that I can knock out a simple scaffold application with one of the default property types. I can accept your answer but I consider it to be an ugly workaround. I believe Grails should handle it internally.